# Update query is not working in my sql procedure.why?

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Sp_IU_Group(
    GID int,
    GroupName nvarchar(200),
    UserID int,
    Status int

)
BEGIN
IF GID=0 THEN
    Insert into tblGroup (GroupName,UserID,Status)
            values (GroupName,UserID,Status);
else
        update tblGroup set GroupName=GroupName,UserID=UserID,Status=Status WHERE GID=GID;
END IF;
END
```

Comment: Giving your columns and your variables *the same exact names* seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Can you define "not working"? - Are you seeing an error message?

Comment: no any error it has updated all row.

Answer (score 0):

This query:

```
update tblGroup set GroupName=GroupName,UserID=UserID,Status=Status WHERE GID=GID
```

Will update *every* record in the table... *to itself*.  This matches every record, because this is *always* true:

```
WHERE GID=GID
```

And this updates a value *to itself*:

```
GroupName=GroupName
```

The problem is that you're using *the same names* for multiple things.  Give things different names.  Something as simple as this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Sp_IU_Group(
    GIDNew int,
    GroupNameNew nvarchar(200),
    UserIDNew int,
    StatusNew int
)
```

(Or use any other standard you want to distinguish the variables from the database objects, such as prepending them with a special character like an `@`.)

Then the query can tell the difference:

```
update tblGroup set GroupName=GroupNameNew,UserID=UserIDNew,Status=StatusNew WHERE GID=GIDNew
```

(Modify the rest of the stored procedure for the new variable names accordingly, of course.)

Basically, as a general rule of thumb, never rely on the code to "know what you meant".  Always be explicit and unambiguous.